# How to fix "cannot be aplied to" error in activity class?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a database on SQLite, but have a error with adding it in Main Activity. I'm sure I made all right in building database.

Tried to change on activity name - nothing changed. Tried change on getActivity() - got a new error.

Code from Main activity (part with error):

```
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;

DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);

    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}
```

...

Database code (called DBHelper in my project):

```
package com.gov.work;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactDb";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_MAIL = "mail";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name,  int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key,"+ KEY_MAIL + " text," + KEY_PASSWORD + " text" + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

When I try to run project it gives me compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're trying to instantiate your `DBHelper` with:

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

but you didn't have a matching constructor in your `DBHelper`. You only have the following constructor:

```
public DBHelper(Context context, String name,  int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

So, you need to add a constructor to `DBHelper` with `Context` as its only parameter to solve your problem, like this:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use getActivity() instead this

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
```

to

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
```